# Path to user desktop using python

Tags: windows, python, paths

This may seem stupid to a few, but I was wondering if there was some code to find out the operating system  of the present user, and then the path to his Desktop using python.

Comment: There are a few answers in [this Stackoverflow question][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7403918/cross-platform-desktop-directory-path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a default Ubuntu running Python 2.7 you can use the following commands

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import platform

userhome = os.path.expanduser('~')
desktop = userhome + '/Desktop/'
useros = platform.system() # returns e.g. 'Linux' 'Windows' 
distribution = platform.linux_distribution() 'in case it's a Unix
```

When coding a cross platfrom application you should be aware that not all desktop environments make use of a desktop directory. This will even be true for some XDG desktops.

- Our code should therefore not rely on the presence of a desktop directory.

In case you code for different locales you need to parse the name given for the desktop directory from the users's xdg desktop configuration (see [How can I get the (XDG) Default User Directories from Python?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457047/how-can-i-get-the-xdg-default-user-directories-from-python)).

Comment: This is sweet. Works like a charm on Ubuntu. But  will this print the correct path to the desktop even if its a Windows system?

Comment: Path to the windows `/Desktop/`-analogue will be different. Nevertheless will the above command give you the path to the current user's HOME on Windows too. Can't test this further here due to a tremendous lack of Windows - you may need some experimenting ;)

Comment: /Desktop/ is not always right when exists l18n folder. For example,  for spanish is /Escritorio/. This is taken from XDG_DESKTOP_DIR in ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs

Comment: @shakaran: thank you for this useful note. You may `try` to get `os.environ['XDG_DESKTOP_DIR']`. Note that if it is not defined (which may likely be the case) this will throw an error on your user.

Comment: @Takkat I know it. Currently I am using subprocess.check_output(['xdg-user-dir', 'DESKTOP']) for detect the values. You can see a live example on my project "pygifme" in github: https://github.com/shakaran/pygifme/blob/master/pygifme.py#L193 I  hope that helps to others

Comment: This only works on English installations and if the user left the desktop folder setting on the default `$HOME/Desktop`. An XDG-compliant solution would need to evaluate the `XDG_DESKTOP` setting in `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/user-dirs.cfg`. -1

Comment: @DavidFoerster thanks.  All this is true only if we have an XDG desktop that uses a desktop directory at all. It's probably better to not expect its presence when coding.

Comment: All official Ubuntu flavours have default desktop environment that comply with that part of the XDG specification. If a DE doesn't comply than I doubt that there's any DE-agnostic notion of "desktop directory". Windows and OS X are another thing obviously…

Answer (score 1):

```
import subprocess
import os.path

try:
    return subprocess.check_output(['xdg-user-dir', 'DESKTOP'])
except:
    return os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop")
```