# How can I get the (XDG) Default User Directories from Python?

Tags: python, xdg, xdg-base-directory

By example,
In English the default user folders will be:

```
$HOME/Desktop
....
$HOME/Videos
```

In Spanish the default user folders will be:

```
$HOME/Escritorio
....
$HOME/Vídeos
```

[The file](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xdg_user_directories) `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` has those localize names for the default folders. (Always?).

I need to get those names from a python script. I'd like not to parse that file. Is there other elegant way?
I found [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1692936):

```
from xdg.BaseDirectory import *
print xdg_cache_home
print xdg_config_dirs
print xdg_config_home
print xdg_data_dirs
print xdg_data_home
```

But it doesn't return those folders.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't mind getting a dependency on `GLib` or if you're already using `GTK` as toolkit, you can use the [`GLib.get_user_special_dir()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.40/glib-Miscellaneous-Utility-Functions.html#g-get-user-special-dir) method.

```
>>> from gi.repository import GLib
>>> GLib.get_user_special_dir(GLib.USER_DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
'/home/timo/Afbeeldingen'
>>> GLib.get_user_special_dir(GLib.USER_DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)
'/home/timo/Documenten'
>>> GLib.get_user_special_dir(GLib.USER_DIRECTORY_DOWNLOAD)
'/home/timo/Downloads'
```

All [available](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.40/glib-Miscellaneous-Utility-Functions.html#GUserDirectory) directories:

```
G_USER_DIRECTORY_DESKTOP         the user's Desktop directory
G_USER_DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS       the user's Documents directory
G_USER_DIRECTORY_DOWNLOAD        the user's Downloads directory
G_USER_DIRECTORY_MUSIC           the user's Music directory
G_USER_DIRECTORY_PICTURES        the user's Pictures directory
G_USER_DIRECTORY_PUBLIC_SHARE    the user's shared directory
G_USER_DIRECTORY_TEMPLATES       the user's Templates directory
G_USER_DIRECTORY_VIDEOS          the user's Movies directory
G_USER_N_DIRECTORIES             the number of enum values
```

If you get this error message:

> ImportError: When using gi.repository you must not import static
>   modules like "gobject". Please change all occurrences of "import
>   gobject" to "from gi.repository import GObject".

You need to use this:

```
import glib
return glib.get_user_special_dir(glib.USER_DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
```

Comment: I get this warning: `PyGIDeprecationWarning: GLib.USER_DIRECTORY_PICTURES is deprecated; use GLib.UserDirectory.DIRECTORY_PICTURES instead`

Answer (score 6):

### Install the python library to access freedesktop.org standards

To get the XDG directories from Python you need to install [PyXDG](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/pyxdg/). You can install it using APT (depending on your python version) using one of the following packages:

For Python 2.x

```
sudo apt-get install python-xdg
```

For Python 3:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-xdg
```

You can also [install it from PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/pyxdg/#files).

### XDG Directories

- `$XDG_DATA_HOME` defines the base directory relative to which user specific data files should be stored. If `$XDG_DATA_HOME` is either not set or empty, a default equal to `$HOME/.local/share` should be used.
- `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` defines the base directory relative to which user specific configuration files should be stored. If `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` is either not set or empty, a default equal to `$HOME/.config` should be used.
- `$XDG_DATA_DIRS` defines the preference-ordered set of base directories to search for data files in addition to the `$XDG_DATA_HOME` base directory. The directories in `$XDG_DATA_DIRS` should be separated with a colon ':'.

  If `$XDG_DATA_DIRS` is either not set or empty, a value equal to `/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/` should be used.
- `$XDG_CONFIG_DIRS` defines the preference-ordered set of base directories to search for configuration files in addition to the `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` base directory. The directories in `$XDG_CONFIG_DIRS` should be seperated with a colon ':'.

  If `$XDG_CONFIG_DIRS` is either not set or empty, a value equal to `/etc/xdg` should be used.

Source: http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html

### UPDATE: How to access Ubuntu specific XDG user directories:

The `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` file will always contain the localize names as the [xdg-user-dirs-update](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/xdg-user-dirs-update.1.html) tool controls this file, see the dedicated man page section:

> ```
>    The XDG user dirs configuration is stored in the user-dirs.dir
>    file in the location pointed to by the XDG_CONFIG_HOME
>    environment variable.
> ```

The following python code will allow you to parse the `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import io
import os
import re
import ConfigParser

from xdg.BaseDirectory import xdg_config_home

config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser(allow_no_value=True)

f = open(os.path.join(xdg_config_home, "user-dirs.dirs"))
user_config = "[XDG_USER_DIR]\n" + f.read()
f.close()
user_config = re.sub('\$HOME', os.path.expanduser("~"), user_config)
user_config = re.sub('"', '', user_config)

config.readfp(io.BytesIO(user_config))
print config.get("XDG_USER_DIR", "XDG_PICTURES_DIR")
```

Comment: Thanks @Sylvain, but it appears not to work :O http://paste.ubuntu.com/7352802/ I need $HOME/Documents, $HOME/Pictures, etc.

Comment: I've updated my answer to parse those values

Comment: Thanks @Sylvain Pineau! Then there isn't a solution without parse the file?

Comment: There's no dedicated python module except the one providing the original freedesktop values so I guess that parsing this file is the only solution.

Comment: In Python 3, ConfigParser has been renamed to configparser for PEP 8 compliance.

Comment: `pip install xdg`

Answer (score 0):

**I am still seeing this issue on Ubuntu 22.04 in December 2022.**

What I realized is that

```
/usr/lib/python3.10 and ~/.local/lib/python3.10
```

don't have a dist-packages or xdg.
But
`/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/` has xdg which has the `BaseDirectory.py` and others.

What ended up working for me was copying the file to my home path:

```
cp /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/xdg/BaseDirectory.py ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/xdg/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
XDG_DATA_DIRS = os.environ.get("XDG_DATA_DIRS")
```

Repeat for your other XDG directories.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to install any dependencies, you can [follow the spec](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html) to write your own code, or copy the code found in [`BaseDirectory.py`](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/xdg/pyxdg/tree/xdg/BaseDirectory.py). The code is pretty straight-forward:

```py
import os

_home = os.path.expanduser('~')

xdg_data_home = os.environ.get('XDG_DATA_HOME') or \
            os.path.join(_home, '.local', 'share')

xdg_config_home = os.environ.get('XDG_CONFIG_HOME') or \
            os.path.join(_home, '.config')
```